# Calculate required height to make scaled down div reach the bottom viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I'm using CSS transform: scale(0.6) to scale down a div. When the element is scaled down, it maintains its aspect ratio. However, in my case, this element needs to always have a height that will reach the bottom of the viewport. This means I need to adjust the height of the element while keeping its width and top position the same.

How do I calculate the height I need to apply so that the element reaches the bottom of the viewport exactly when transform: scale(x) is applied?

below is a codesnippet. Clicking anywhere scales the div down and it's when I should apply the new height to allow the div height to reach the bottom of the viewport while keeping the same width, and position.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('div')[0].style.transform = 'scale(0.44)';
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  width: 350px;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: top;
}
```

```html
<div><h1>TEST</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the div's height to stretch till bottom, you can make use of `window.innerHeight` here.

The new height can be calculated using the following formula :-

`newHeight = (viewportHeight - offsetTop)*(1/scaleValue)`

Putting in values it will come down to the following calculation :-

`newHeight = (window.innerHeight - div.offsetTop)*(1/0.44)`

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const div = document.querySelectorAll('div')[0];
  div.style.transform = 'scale(0.44)';
  div.style.height = `${(window.innerHeight-div.offsetTop)*(1/0.44)}px`
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  width: 350px;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>TEST</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i see you position it from the top. i think that if you position it from bottom you will get what u want.

change top to bottom: 0px

change tranform-origin to transform-origin:bottom

and for calculating the height u could use 100VH instead of 100%